# Custom button issues

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am making a custom button on a list view so I can have users select multiple records and update 1 field from blank or false to TRUE. This is to kick off other actions. (this is in the customer community through VF)

Custom object is Part__c
Field to change Request_Update__c
Value to change to TRUE

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 

var url = parent.location.href; 
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Part__c)}; 
var updateRecords = []; 

if (records[0] == null) { 
alert("Please select at least one record to update."); 
} else { 
var update_Part__c= new sforce.SObject("Parts"); 
update_Part__c.Id = records[a]; 
update_Part__c.Request_update__c = "TRUE"; 
updateRecords.push(update_Part__c); 
} 
result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 
parent.location.href = url; //refresh the page 
}
```

If anyone can help I would appreciate this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
update_Part__c.Id = records[a];
```

will be `update_Part__c.Id = records[0];`

---

Complete code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")} 

var url = parent.location.href; 
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Part__c)}; 
var updateRecords = []; 

if (records[0] == null) { 
    alert("Please select at least one record to update."); 
} else { 
var update_Part__c= new sforce.SObject("Parts"); 
update_Part__c.Id = records[0]; 
update_Part__c.Request_update__c = "TRUE"; 
updateRecords.push(update_Part__c);  
result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 
parent.location.href = url; //refresh the page 
}
```

Comment: I still get an error "Unexpected token }"

Comment: @Jason use my Completed code..

Comment: Finally got an actionable error. Your the man Ratan.